# Cant launch chromium from snap

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium, apparmor

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (odroid aarch64).
When I try to launch chromium:

```
cannot perform operation: mount --bind /snap/core20/current/etc/nsswitch.conf /tmp/snap.rootfs_IbY3Iu/etc/nsswitch.conf: Permission denied
```

I tried same with sudo but still permission denied.
I tried also `sudo snap refresh chromium` but it displays same error.

This also did not help: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install snapd chromium-browser`,

How to solve this problem? And why is it trying to mount nsswitch.conf (regular ASCII text file) and why sudo doesnt help with permissions?

Edit:
I found the problem. This is caused by apparmor:

```
sudo dmesg | grep DENIED
[   20.334810] audit: type=1400 audit(1659685604.695:10): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" profile="/snap/snapd/16299/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/tmp/snap.rootfs_IAZptT/var/lib/extrausers/" pid=3805 comm="snap-confine" flags="rw, rbind"
[   20.336912] audit: type=1400 audit(1659685604.695:11): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed mntpnt match" error=-13 profile="/snap/snapd/16299/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/tmp/snap.rootfs_IAZptT/etc/nsswitch.conf/" pid=3805 comm="snap-confine" srcname="/snap/core20/1590/etc/nsswitch.conf/" flags="rw, bind"
[   53.546374] audit: type=1400 audit(1659685657.956:12): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" profile="/snap/snapd/16299/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/tmp/snap.rootfs_oUOX9j/var/lib/extrausers/" pid=4207 comm="snap-confine" flags="rw, rbind"
[   53.546449] audit: type=1400 audit(1659685657.956:13): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mount" info="failed mntpnt match" error=-13 profile="/snap/snapd/16299/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/tmp/snap.rootfs_oUOX9j/etc/nsswitch.conf/" pid=4207 comm="snap-confine" srcname="/snap/core20/1590/etc/nsswitch.conf/" flags="rw, bind"
```

How to fix this? Should I disable apparmor?
PS: I've tried to `sudo systemctl disable apparmor` but after reboot problem persists. So I need different way than disabling it, I need to properly configure apparmor to allow snap, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with one of the apparmor profiles

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1675772818.295:1707): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mkdir" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/tmp/snap-private-tmp/" pid=11690 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0FSUID="root" OUID="root"
```

you may not have taken the package updated version, eg:

```
# diff /etc/apparmor.git/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real.dpkg-new
163a164
>     /tmp/snap.rootfs_*/ rw,
316,317c317,319
<     /tmp/snap.*/ rw,
<     /tmp/snap.*/tmp/ rw,
---
>     /tmp/snap-private-tmp/ rw,
>     /tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.*/ rw,
>     /tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.*/tmp/ rw,
319c321
<     mount options=(rw bind) /tmp/snap.*/tmp/ -> /tmp/,
---
>     mount options=(rw bind) /tmp/snap-private-tmp/snap.*/tmp/ -> /tmp/,
```

this fixed it for me:

```
sudo mv -f usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real.dpkg-new /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real
systemctl restart apparmor
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, on a Odroid ARM machine. I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 22 but problem persists. Not only with chromium but other packages like firefox ends at the same point.

The only working solution is to install the dev version of chromium, since it doesn't come with snap at all. I tried so many tricks and workarrounds but nothing found.

Perhaps we need a snap update with the solution. I think there's something invalid in the configure hook. 2 Months ago I installed chromium with no problem.